# How can I copy a set-cookie from a `fetch()` response to my middleware response?

Tags: javascript, next.js, cookies

I'm writing some middleware for Next.js 13 that looks more or less like this

```js
// middleware.js

import { cookies } from "next/headers"
import { NextResponse } from "next/server"

export async function middleware(request) {
  const { pathname, origin, search, searchParams } = request.nextUrl
  let response = NextResponse.next()

  // If the search params includes refreshIDToken=true,
  // refresh the user's id token by calling the sessionLogin() api endpoint
  if (searchParams.get("refreshIDToken") === "true") {

    // Get the current session cookie
    const sessionCookie = cookies().get("sessionCookie")

    // Re-login. This returns a new session cookie
    const sessionLoginResponse = await fetch(`${origin}/api/sessionLogin`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ idToken: sessionCookie.value }),
    })

    // === Code I'd like to refactor starts here =====================

    // Extract the cookie and attach it to the response
    const sessionCookieHeader = sessionLoginResponse.headers.getSetCookie()[0]
    const sessionCookieVal = /^sessionCookie=([^;]+)/.exec(
      sessionCookieHeader
    )

    if (sessionCookieVal) {
      response.cookies.set({
        name: "sessionCookie",
        value: sessionCookieVal[1],
        maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 5 * 1000,
        sameSite: "lax",
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: true,
        path: "/",
      })
    }

    // === Code I'd like to refactor ends here =====================
  }

  return response
}
```

That block of code at the end does something which feels icky (like I'm reinventing the wheel in a bad way). `sessionCookieHeader` already has the attributes I want, so my code to extract the cookie value and reset the attributes is both wasteful and redundant.

I would prefer to do something like this

```js
const newSessionCookie = sessionLoginResponse.cookies.get("sessionCookie")
response.cookies.set("sessionCookie", newSessionCookie)
```

but I couldn't figure out how to implement it.

Comment: does the code work as intended?

Comment: @JaromandaX yes, it *works*, but that doesn't mean it's good :)

Comment: I get that, just checking so I can easily see what you're attempting :p

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but if you create a function like

```
const getCookies = response => Object.fromEntries(response.headers.getSetCookie().map(cookie => {
    const [key, ...value] = cookie.split('=');
    return [key, value.join('=')];
}));
```

Then you could use it like

```
const newSessionCookie = getCookies(sessionLoginResponse).sessionCookie;
response.cookies.set("sessionCookie", newSessionCookie);
```

Note: this also alleviates a potential bug, what if the first cookie ISN'T the `sessionCookie`?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this up. I had to modify this slightly, as cookies can have trailing attributes like `sessionCookie=Xu2Gf01n; sameSite=lax; httpOnly=true;`. In fact, I want to copy all of those attributes as well. While this is helpful, it still seems unnecessarily complicated. Giggity.

Comment: @Ben, to be honest, I didn't even know about `getSetCookie` until this question (I think it's a fairly recent addition to `headers`,lie April of this year) - as far as the trailing attributes go, I didn't know they came across in the getSetCookie array - as I said, untested :p I know it's still complicated, but what you want doesn't seem to exist, so, you have to write it yourself :p